# Ставить ли тире или запятую при приложении

Tags: пунктуация

В предложении: "Выступала учащаяся школы №1, лауреат региональных конкурсов (-/,) Елена Иванова" должно быть тире или запятая?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё правильно, перед именем собственным запятой нет: Выступала **учащаяся школы №1, лауреат региональных конкурсов**  Елена Иванова.

Это необособленный ряд однородных приложений.

Что касается примера, то там немного другая ситуация: Верстах в пятнадцати от моего имения живёт один мне знакомый человек, **молодой помещик, гвардейский офицер в отставке,** Аркадий Павлыч Пеночкин.

В этом случае два приложения являются **уточняющими** и при чтении выделяются паузами и общим понижением тона (вставочная интонация).

**Сравнить:** Верстах в пятнадцати от моего имения живёт **один мне знакомый человек** Аркадий Павлыч Пеночкин (нет знаков, приложение + имя собственное).

Answer (score 1):

В предложении: *"Выступала учащаяся школы №1, лауреат региональных конкурсов Елена Иванова*" **ни тире, ни запятая** после слова *конкурсов* **не нужны**. **Интонационной паузы после слова *конкурсов* нет**, как **нет и причины** обособлять фразу *лауреат региональных конкурсов*. Запятая после №1 нужна, потому что дальше действительно следует приложение.

Comment: Просто у Д. Э. Розенталя есть пример: "Верстах в пятнадцати от моего имения живёт один мне знакомый человек, молодой помещик, гвардейский офицер в отставке, Аркадий Павлыч Пеночкин ". Там стоит запятая перед собственным именем. Разве приведенное предложение не аналогичное?

Comment: В примере Розенталя дано несколько рапространённых приложений подряд, пишущихся через запятую, конечно. Но запятая перед Аркадий Павлыч Пеночкин не обязательна. Это авторская запятая, можно написать и прочитать без интонационной паузы (и запятой соответственно) гвардейский офицер в отставке Аркадий Павлыч Пеночкин.